# Random errors in TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I detected a very strange behaviour in *WebStorm 2017.2* while editing a TypeScript file.

In a specific line an error is displayed, that does not make any sense. In line 107 it says

> TS2339:Property '_' does not exist on type 'NjPropertiesBoSettings'.

But I imported lodash as

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

When I now add a linebreak before that error line, the error is gone.

**Error**

[image]

**new line and the error wanders**

[image]

**new line and the error is gone**

[image]

Has anybody an idea what the problem here? I only got WebStorm errors, the TypeScript compiler does not mention anything.

**EDIT**

I found the reason. I disabled the "Use TypeScript Service" checkbox unter `Settings->Languages & Frameworks->TypeScript`.

Seemingly this causes the error, because I am not building a Angular2+ project.

**Note**

I will leave this here, in case someone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I disabled the "Use TypeScript Service" checkbox unter Settings->Languages & Frameworks->TypeScript.

Seemingly this causes the error, because I am not building a Angular2+ project.

Comment: `TS2339` prefix in error message indicates that the error comes from Typescript service - looks as if it's enabled. What Typescript version is chosen in Settings->Languages & Frameworks->TypeScript? If it's 2.6 or higher, make sure to change it to the bundled version. Typescript service integration is broken for 2.6+ because of breaking API changes, and 'misplaced' error messages is one of possible symptoms

Comment: i have a similar problem in vscode. is there a fix for this too?